# Replicating Blender bezier curves in a C++ program

Tags: c++, math, blender, bezier

I'm trying to export (3D) bezier curves from Blender to my C++ program. [I asked a related question a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307015/evaluating-3d-splines-exported-from-max-in-a-c-program), where I was successfully directed to use De Casteljau's Algorithm to evaluate points (and tangents to these points) along a bezier curve. This works well. In fact, perfectly. I can export the curves and evaluate points along the curve, as well as the tangent to these points, all within my program using De Casteljau's Algorithm.

However, in 3D space a point along a bezier curve and the tangent to this point is *not enough* to define a "frame" that a camera can lock into, if that makes sense. To put it another way, there is no "up vector" which is required for a camera's orientation to be properly specified at any point along the curve. Mathematically speaking, there are an infinite amount of normal vectors at any point along a 3D bezier curve.

I've noticed when constructing curves in Blender that *they aren't merely infinitely thin lines*, they actually appear to have a proper 3D orientation defined at any point along them (as shown by the offshooting "arrow lines" in the screenshot below). *I'd like to replicate what blender does here as closely as possible in my program. That is, I'd like to be able to form a matrix that represents an orientation at any point along a 3D bezier curve (almost exactly as it would in Blender itself).*

[image]

Can anyone lend further guidance here, perhaps someone with an intimate knowledge of Blender's source code? (But *any* advice is welcome, Blender background or not.) I know it's open source, but I'm having a lot of troubles isolating the code responsible for these curve calculations due to the vastness of the program.

Comment: Have a look at [Frenet frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) - or parallel transport frames to avoid degenerate cases. The basis vectors probably won't be analytic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some weeks ago, I have found a solution to this problem. I post it here, in case someone else would need it :

1) For a given point `P0`, calculate the tangent vector `T0`.

One simple, easy way, is to take next point on the curve, subtract current point, then normalize result :

`T0 = normalize(P1 - P0)`

Another, more precise way, to get tangent is to calculate the derivative of your bezier curve function.

Then, pick an arbitrary vector `V` (for example, you can use `(0, 0, 1)`)

Make `N0 = crossproduct(T0, V)` and `B0 = crossproduct(T0, N0)` (dont forget to normalize result vectors after each operation)

You now have a starting set of coordinates ( `P0`, `B0`, `T0`, `N0`)

[image]

This is the initial camera orientation.

2) Then, to calculate next points and their orientation :

Calculate `T1` using same method as `T0`

Here is the trick, new reference frame is calculated from previous frame :

`N1 = crossproduct(B0, T1)`

`B1 = crossproduct(T1, N1)`

[image]

Proceed using same method for other points. It will results of having camera slightly rotating around tangent vector depending on how curve change its direction. Loopings will be handled correctly (camera wont twist like in my previous answer)

You can watch a live example here (not from me) : http://jabtunes.com/labs/3d/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html

Comment: Awesome answer! I think you've got it :)

Comment: Here is reference document I used : [Calculation of reference frames along a space curve (Graphics Gems, 1990)](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~blob/courses/305/notes/pdf/ref-frames.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correcly, what you want is to get 3 orientation vectors (left, front, up) for any point of the curve.

Here is a simple method (  there is a limitation, (*) see below ) :

**1) Front vector :**

Calculate a 3d point on bezier curve for a given position (t). This is the point for which we will calculate front, left, up vectors. We will call it `current_point`.

Calculate another 3d point on the curve, next to first one (t + 0.01), let's call it `next_point`.

*Note : i don't write formula here, because i believe you already how to
do that.*

Then, to calculate front vector, just substract the two points calculated previously :

```
vector front = next_point - current_point
```

Don't forget to normalize the result.

**2) Left vector**

Define a temporary "up" vector

```
vector up = vector(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Now you can calculate left easily, using front and up :

```
vector left = CrossProduct(front, up);
```

**3) Up vector**

```
vector up = CrossProduct(left, front);
```

Using this method you can always calculate a front, left, up for any point along the curve.

---

(*) NOTE : this wont work in all cases. Imagine you have a loop in you curve, just like a rollercoaster loop. On the top of the loop your calculated up vector will be (0, 1, 0), while you maybe want it to be (0, -1, 0). Only way to solve that is to have two curves : one for points and one for up vectors (from which left and front can be calculated easily).

Comment: If you use a temporary up to calculate left and then that left to calculate up, you will end up with the same "temporary" up vector (0, 1, 0). Notice, that the curve is three-dimensional, so the 0, 1, 0 choice for "up" won't always work (for example, if the curve follows the Y axis). You have to make that up vector depend on local curvature and direction of curve.

Comment: I know choosing 0,1,0 for up wont always work, this was my "note" remark at bottom. But i dont agree about final "up" vector being the same than temporary "up". Final "up" vector is calculated using left AND front and thus in most cases will be different than temporary. Think about the climb in a rollercoaster.

Comment: @Spook Imagine that the forward vector is sloping down. It and the temporary up still define a plane from which a left vector can be determined. Even though the two vectors are not perpendicular. If the left and forward vector will be used subsequently to calculate a new up vector, this will be perpendicular to left and forward. Something which the original up was not. I assume this is what user1083855 is referring to.

Comment: Ok, I see now, I was wrong, it will be a different vector indeed. However, the new "up" vector will lie on the plane determined by front and up vectors, while the "up" vector on the Blender's Bezier spline does not always point "up"...

Answer (score 1):

Primarily, we know, that the normal vector you're searching for lies on the plane "locally perpendicular" to the curve on the specific point. So the real problem is to choose a single vector on this plane.

I've made an empty object to track the curve and noticed, that it behave similarly to the cart of a rollercoaster: its "up" vector was correlated to the centrifugal force while it was moving along the curve. This one can be uniquely evaluated from the local shape of the curve.

I'm not very good at physics, but I would try to estimate that vector by evaluating two planes: the first is previously mentioned perpendicular plane and the second is a plane made of three neighboring points of a curve segment (if the curve is not straight, these will form a triangle, which describes exactly one plane). Intersection of these two planes will give you an axis and you'll only have to choose a direction of such calculated normal vector.

Comment: Your answer is the best so far, in the sense that it seems most likely to be what Blender uses on the 'minimum' setting. The problem is this breaks down when the curve isn't straight, as you rightly mention. This doesn't appear to be the case in Blender. In the end I decided to "bake" the normals of the curve within blender at regular intervals, and interpolate them linearly within the game, which appears to do the job satisfactorily for now..